# Custom Keyboard on Custom Dialog (Android)

Tags: android, dialog, keyboard

How can I use custom keyboard when open custom dialog with EditText ?

I use keyboard View in my project ,I wanna show my custom keyboard when open custom dialog

- **When custom dialog is open, my custom keyboard open behind dialog**

When custom dialog is displayed keyboard is displayed behind that and thus user is not able to type using the keyboard.
Something like this

[image: Something like this: Sample image]

Comment: One solution is replacing the dialog with a activity that the content layout consists of the original dialog layout widgets on  a transparent  backgroud.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this tutorial [Create Your Own Custom Keyboard](http://tutorials-android.blogspot.in/2011/06/create-your-own-custom-keyboard-for.html)

in additional in order to intercept the keyboard events you can overrider the `onTouch`  events see the link i posted

Comment: My Problem is ,when custom dialog is open, my custom keyboard open behind dialog

Comment: in order to display your keyboard above the dialog, add this flag before displaying keyboard 

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

Comment: @TomerMor I have same issue. I'm using my custom keyboard with DialogFragment but keyboard comes behind dialog. Above solution is not working. this is the code I have written in onTouchEvent before making keyboard visible : getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);

Comment: Guys are u find any answer?

Comment: I tried both getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM); and getDialog().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM); both not working