# How to get custom keyboard to show in front of AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android

I am working on making a custom keyboard using [this guide](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm) and it seems to work except when I try to use it for an EditText in an AlertDialog. I've tried setting flags as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144608/custom-keyboard-on-custom-dialog-android) but that does not seem to make a difference. Any ideas on how to make it show correctly?

Comment: Did u find any answer?