# React-native modal dialog hides custom keyboard

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog

We're using a [custom keyboard](https://github.com/3sidedcube/react-native-custom-keyboard) in react-native which works fine (this is android only, no iOS needed here), but has a problem when used together with a modal dialog.

As shown on the screen shot below, the keyboard pops up *below* the modal, making it impossible to input any value. We've tried several options for modal components, including the default react-native Modal component, but they all give the same result.

This [SO comment on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144608/custom-keyboard-on-custom-dialog-android#comment26530326_16144672) made me think it could have to do with the flags set on the modal dialog as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html):

> Often you will want to have a Dialog display on top of the current input method, because there is no reason for it to accept text. You can do this by setting the WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM window flag (assuming your Dialog takes input focus, as it the default) with the following code:

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
```

But when we use a standard android keyboard, it shows above the modal as expected, so that does not seem to be the problem.
The keyboard is in fact started as a separate RN app with this:

```
rootView.startReactApplication(
    ((ReactApplication) activity.getApplication()).getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager(),
            "CustomKeyboard",
            bundle);

final float scale = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Math.round(216*scale));
lParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
layout.addView(rootView, lParams);
```

and it is then shown upon focusing the text input with:

```
activity.addContentView(keyboard, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

I don't know android, but I suspect I need to pass some extra params like [these](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) when creating the content view to ensure it can rise above my modals. Am I on the right track? Any hints as to what those params might be?

EDIT:
Here's a part of the relevant code (I think). `react-native-modal` is [this one](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal), but using react-native's default modal component gives the same result:

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
...(parent component code)...
render() {
    ...
    <Modal isVisible={this.state.isShowingDialog}>
    ...(modal box content, all inside a <View>)...
    </Modal>
    ...
}
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to post the RN code for the modal u are using

Comment: @IsmailIqbal I edited the question with some code. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your activity has this attribute then remove it:

```
<activity 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: This attribute doesn't seem to be anywhere in our code. I checked the app's `AndroidManifest.xml` but it isn't there either.